# Header file class member function declaration error: "incomplete type ' ' name in nested name specifier"

Tags: c++, syntax

I just split a C++ program that i'm writing up into multiple files.

Now I am getting this error for every member function declaration.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 3 class Office{
  4     private:
  5         static const int IDLE = 0, BUSY = 1;
  6         const int num_tellers;
  7         int students_served;
  8 
  9         vector<double> que;                                                   // a vector que which holds the arrival times of students entering an Office
 10         vector<int> tellers;                                                 // a vector to hold the status (IDLE or BUSY) of the tellers                *** INITIALIZED TO SIZE tellers[num_tellers] IN CONSTRUCTOR ***
 11 
 12 
 13         variate_generator<mt19937, exponential_distribution<> > serve_time;  // random variable, determines the time it takes a teller to serve a student
 14 
 15     public:
 16 
 17         Office(double const office_mean, int const num_tellers) : num_tellers(num_tellers), tellers(vector<int>(num_tellers, IDLE)),
 18                                                                   serve_time(variate_generator< mt19937, exponential_distribution<> >( mt19937(time(0)), exponential_distribution<>( 1 / office_mean))){
 19         }                                                // initialize tellers vector to size num_tellers w/ tellers[i] = IDLE, accumulated times to , and initializes serve_time random variable




 37 int Office::departure_destination(Event* departure) {     // returns the next destination of a student departing from an Office
 38 
 39     if (departure->depart_from == AID) {
 40         return determine_destination(.15, .15, 0, 0, .70);
 41     else if (departure->depart_from == PARKING)
 42         return next_destination = determine_destination(.3, 0, 0, 0, .7);
 43     else if (departure->depart_from == REGISTRAR)
 44         return next_destination = determine_destination(.25, 0, .1, 0, .65);
 45     else if (departure->depart_from == BURSAR)
 46         return next_destination = determine_destination(0, .1, .2, .1, .60);
 47     else
 48         return -1;
 49 }
 50
```

then in the header file

```
 57 int Office::departure_destination(Event* departure);
```

Comment: Some code would be a good start.

Comment: well it's like 600 lines or so, i could post the header though i guess..

Comment: Make a smaller example with one function and nothing else. The preferable thing is the smallest compilable sample that exhibits the error.

Comment: Well, what I described was an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). What we want to see so we can help you is something we can copy-paste and try ourselves with minimal effort to figure out the code itself. Thus, if it's doing that for every member function, why not just leave one in to show us?

Comment: @user1647959 chris is suggesting that you take the time to produce a **small complete** example of the problem you're having.  It's work, but asking everyone to guess the rest of your code doesn't go over well.  Make a tiny two file program that's giving you errors, and then show the entire program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Follow these rules and you should end up with something pretty close:

1. Put classes, typedefs, #defines, templates, and inline functions in header files
2. Wrap your header files with #ifndef/#define/#endif so that accidental multiple inclusions don't cause mult defined symbols
3. Put your implementation in your c++ files, and include this headers that have (1).

The easiest way to understand this is to realize that nothing in a header file generates actual machine instructions or data. Everything in a header is declarative. It describes how something *would* generate code or data if it were used, for example, to declare a variable. Your C++ files need these "outlines" in order to understand what you want when you try to call some function in another file, invoke a method on an object, etc.

All of the #define kind of instructions are text processing.

Template are actually a turing-complete language, but they don't generate code until you make something with them...and then it is sorta like they are generating their own C++ files.

Class declarations define what an object would have in it, should you chose to make one.

So, a typical header file (say my_header) will look like this:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER

extern int global;

class A {
   ... data declarations, inline functions ...
   public:
      void f();
};

#endif
```

and the C++ file:

```
#include "my_header"

int global; // only in ONE C file...this  generates real data

void A::f() { ... generates real code to be linked to ... }
```

Comment: Well, you certainly got the problem in there: There's no function declaration. I was about to post that small bit, but this is good beyond just that issue for people new to splitting classes.

Comment: welp. that'll do it haha. Thanks both of you. sorry for poor preparation on my part